# How to disable Traffic view in Azure Traffic Manager?

Tags: azure, azure-traffic-manager

I enabled new "Traffic view" service in Traffic Manager, but for now i don't see any options to disable it.
It's possible using cli or somethings other way?

Answer (score 0):

How can I turn off Traffic View?
During the preview period, you need to create a [support ticket](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request) to disable Traffic View for your subscription.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-faqs#traffic-view